# HTML5 - notification does not allow tag <select> (combobox)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, notifications, web-notifications

I use HTML5 notification in Google Chrome.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification("page.html")
notification.show()
```

On my page, I have `<select>` and several `<option>`'s. But I can not open up the selector (combobox). Have you tried this before? Could you please help me out of this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome version 17.0.963.56 fixed this issue (I filed [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110275) - but it seems dev team were busy...).

You can even use popup menu in notification window - which was unable in Chrome 16.x.

Thanks Chrome dev team  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it is a browser caching problem?

Because in [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110275) page is described your problem, but it was solved like you did.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me. But that issue was reported by... me  :-) And its status is unconfirmed (till now).

Comment: Oh, can't help you, then, @HiBlack sorry :(